# Aggregating strings across `group by` in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the following schema:

```
create table A
(
    id int primary id
)

create table B
(
    a_id int,
    s varchar(255)
)
```

And then the following query:

```
select A.id, sum(1), ??? concat_join(B.s) ???
from A left join B on A.id = B.a_id group by A.id
```

There is a 1-to-many relation between A and B, so multiple rows will be grouped into one.  The desired behaviour of "concat_join" would be for each B.s in the group join them together into a single string by concatenating them (perhaps with a space seperator).

Is there someway to express this is MySQL 5.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select A.id, sum(1), GROUP_CONCAT(B.s)
from A left join B on A.id = B.a_id 
group by A.id
```

by default, the string is separated by a *comma*. if you want to change it, add `SEPARATOR` keyword,

```
select A.id, sum(1), GROUP_CONCAT(B.s SEPARATOR ';')
from A left join B on A.id = B.a_id 
group by A.id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/362e6/4)